# Maximal Compact Connected group of Isometries

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, homogeneous-spaces

**Question: Let $ M $ be a manifold. Let $ g $ be a metric on $ M $ . Let $ K_g $ be the connected component of the identity in the maximal compact subgroup of the isometry group $ Iso(M,g) $. Does there exists a unique compact connected group $ K_M $ such that, for every metric $ g $ on $ M $, the group $ K_g $ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $ K_M $?  The final restriction I wish to place on $ K_M $ is that  it cannot be chosen to be arbitrarily large. In particular, there must exist at least one metric $ g^* $ on $ M $ such that $ K_{g^*} \cong K_M $.**

Here are some examples:

$ M $, $ K_M $ (a metric $ g^* $ such that $ K_{g^*}=K_M $)

The two sphere $ S^2 $, $ K_{S^2}=SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $ (round metric)

The projective plane $ \mathbb{R}P^2 $, $ K_{\mathbb{R}P^2}=SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $ (round metric)

The two torus $ T^2 $, $ K_{T^2}=SO_2(\mathbb{R}) \times SO_2(\mathbb{R}) $ (flat metric)

The plane, $ K_{\mathbb{R}^2}=SO_2(\mathbb{R}) $ (flat or hyperbolic metric)

The surfaces of genus $ g \geq 2 $, the trivial group (any metric)

I am primarily interested in the case of compact connected manifolds that admit a metric with respect to which the isometry group is homogeneous (i.e. Riemannian homogeneous). For example the sphere, projective plane, and torus.

A negative answer to my question would take the following form: a manifold $ M $ and two metrics $ g_1,g_2 $ on $ M $ such that neither $ K_{g_1} $ nor $ K_{g_2} $ embeds in the other. Here $ K_g $ denotes the connected component of the maximal compact subgroup of the isometry group $ Iso(M,g) $

Certainly such non comparable groups of isometries exists for the same manifold if we allow the group of isometries to be non connected (the square and hexagonal tori) and if we allow the group of isometries to be noncompact (the flat and hyperbolic metrics on the plane). See ["Maximal symmetry" metric for a manifold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82832/maximal-symmetry-metric-for-a-manifold). However I am restricting the the discussion to the case of groups of isometries which are both compact and connected.

Comment: But isn't every surface has a metric with constant curvature, so they still serve as a counterexample?

Comment: I mean, aren't the surfaces of genus $\ge 2$ with constant curvature such an example with no such group action, so the answer to your question is no?

Comment: Ar, so your question is: if $(M, g)$ is homogeneous manifold, say, with a transitively isometric group action by $H$, can one find another $G$ (with those properties) which still acts isometrically and transitively on $M$?

Comment: I am unclear about whether the original manifold is endowed with a fixed Riemannian metric, or whether the question is asking about whether there might exist another group action *and another metric* such that the new group action is isometric with respect to the new metric.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by "maximal". Would you care to define it?

Comment: A natural question to ask would be "where do these embeddings come from?". Expecting them to exist be happenstance doesn't strike me as a satisfactory motivation. If there were a positive answer (and I'm not convinced there is in general), it seems there ought to be some kind of regularization procedure which adds new symmetries without destroying existing ones. Ricci flow comes to mind, but it only works in special cases.

Comment: It's easy to arrange that neither group is contained in the other as a set of diffeomorphisms. Could you please clarify what "embed" (for one isometry group in another) means here? E.g., isomorphic as groups? Conjugate subgroups in the identity component of the group of diffeomorphisms?

Comment: Oh I just meant isomorphic as groups I updated my question

Comment: Thank you for the update. If I understand right, we can still get examples by taking $M$ to be a product of homogeneous spaces with different isometry connected groups (say a round sphere cross a flat torus, which has connected isometry group $SO(3) \times T^2$), then changing the metric on one factor or the other to destroy the isometries on that factor, i.e., obtaining metrics with connected isometry group $SO(3)$ or $T^2$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang that sounds interesting. Could you say more about that or maybe write it up as an answer?